# babelquarto: Rendering a Multilingual Quarto Book

Tags: r, multilingual, quarto, babelquarto

I am currently experimenting with [babelquarto](/questions/tagged/babelquarto) in order to create a Multilingual [quarto](/questions/tagged/quarto) Book, and I have utilized the provided code from the [babelquarto](/questions/tagged/babelquarto) [website](https://github.com/ropensci-review-tools/babelquarto) for this purpose.

```
library(babelquarto)
library(fs)

parent_dir <- getwd()

quarto_multilingual_book(
    parent_dir = parent_dir
  , book_dir   = "blop"
  )

Creating project at D:\2023-06-23_babelquarto\blop:
  - Created _quarto.yml
  - Created index.qmd
  - Created intro.qmd
  - Created summary.qmd
  - Created references.qmd
  - Created cover.png
  - Created references.bib

readLines(file.path(parent_dir, "blop", "_quarto.yml"))

[1] "project:"                         
 [2] "  type: book"                     
 [3] ""                                 
 [4] "book:"                            
 [5] "  title: \"blop\""                
 [6] "  author: \"MYaseen\""            
 [7] "  date: \"6/16/2023\""            
 [8] "  chapters:"                      
 [9] "    - index.qmd"                  
[10] "    - intro.qmd"                  
[11] "    - summary.qmd"                
[12] "    - references.qmd"             
[13] ""                                 
[14] "bibliography: references.bib"     
[15] ""                                 
[16] "format:"                          
[17] "  html:"                          
[18] "    theme: cosmo"                 
[19] ""                                 
[20] "babelquarto:"                     
[21] "  mainlanguage: 'en'"             
[22] "  languages: ['es', 'fr']"        
[23] "title-es: title in es"            
[24] "title-fr: title in fr"            
[25] "description-es: description in es"
[26] "description-fr: description in fr"
[27] "author-es: author in es"          
[28] "author-fr: author in fr"          
[29] "lang: en"       



dir_tree(file.path(parent_dir, "blop"))
D:/2023-06-23_babelquarto/blop
├── cover.png
├── index.es.qmd
├── index.fr.qmd
├── index.qmd
├── intro.es.qmd
├── intro.fr.qmd
├── intro.qmd
├── references.bib
├── references.es.qmd
├── references.fr.qmd
├── references.qmd
├── summary.es.qmd
├── summary.fr.qmd
├── summary.qmd
└── _quarto.yml

library(quarto)
quarto_render("./blop")
```

which renders only four .qmd document as shown below:
[image]

I believe that the provided [r](/questions/tagged/r) should include all three books. However, I'm concerned that I may be overlooking something simple.

**Expected Output**
The expected output is [here](https://devdevguide.netlify.app/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`babelquarto::render_book`](https://docs.ropensci.org/babelquarto/reference/render_book.html), instead of `quarto::quarto_render`,

```
babelquarto::render_book("./blop")
```

It would create the corresponding files for other languages,

```r
> fs::dir_tree("./blop/_book", recurse=FALSE)
./blop/_book
├── es
├── fr
├── index.html
├── intro.html
├── references.html
├── search.json
├── site_libs
└── summary.html
```

---

[image: multilingual quarto websites]

---

#### Issue with Hosting the Multilingual Quarto book with Github-Pages

`babelquarto::render_book` generates the links for multilingual versions in html files (in `index.html`, `intro.html` etc) as the following (excerpt from `index.html`),

```html
<li id="language-link-li-es">
<i class="bi bi-globe2"></i><span> </span><a class="toc-action" href="/es/index.es.html" id="language-link-es">Version in ES</a>
</li>
<li id="language-link-li-fr">
<i class="bi bi-globe2"></i><span> </span><a class="toc-action" href="/fr/index.fr.html" id="language-link-fr">Version in FR</a>
</li>
```

where the links are,

```
/es/index.es.html
/fr/index.fr.html
```

Similarly from the `index.es.html`,

```
/index.html
/fr/index.fr.html
```

And as per my understanding, due to the forward slash in front of these relative links, navigation between multilingual versions does not work well with Github pages.

#### Solution

Here's my naive approach to solving this problem.

I have written the following function that receives the `_book` directory and goes through each HTML file in that directory and add a base URL in front of these language links where the base-url would be the url of github page like `https://<user-name>.github.io/<repo-name>`.

```r
library(rvest)
library(fs)

add_base_url <- function(file_path, base_link) {
  html_content <- rvest::read_html(file_path)
  lang_links <- html_content %>% 
    rvest::html_elements('a[id*="language-link"]') %>% 
    rvest::html_attr("href")
  lang_link_with_baseurl <- paste0(base_link, lang_links)
  raw_html <- paste(readLines(file_path), collapse="\n")
  for (i in seq_along(lang_links)) {
    raw_html <- sub(lang_links[i], lang_link_with_baseurl[i], raw_html)
  }
  return(raw_html)
}

create_abs_lang_link <- function(path, base_link) {
  html_files_path <- fs::dir_ls(path, recurse = TRUE, glob="*.html")
  for (file_path in html_files_path) {
    edited_raw_html <- add_base_url(file_path, base_link)
    writeLines(edited_raw_html, file_path)
  }
}
```

##### Steps:

1. Render and generate the multilingual quarto book,

   ```r
   babelquarto::render_book("./blop")
   ```

   This will generate a directory `_book` with the rendered html files
2. Then pass the `_book` directory to the function `create_abs_lang_link`.

   ```r
   create_abs_lang_link("_book", base_link = "https://<user-name>.github.io/<repo-name>")
   ```

3 . Then host this `_book` directory in github pages. The links should work now.

Here's [an example github repository](https://github.com/shafayetShafee/babelquarto1) and link to [`Quarto Multilinuage Book`](https://shafayetshafee.github.io/babelquarto1/).

Comment: Thanks @shafee for your answer. Your given code render all three books but the tabs `Version in ES` and `Version in FR` are not working as expected. They are broken and not linked properly.

Comment: I assume you have opened the `index.html` from your file system, right? You need to serve the `_book` directory through a web server. Then the link will work (and it will work if you host the website in netlify or quarto pub). You can use [`servr`](https://github.com/yihui/servr) package to test it. Run `Rscript -e "servr::httd()" -b` from the `_book` directory.

Comment: Yes, I did the same way [here](https://myaseen208.com/babelquarto1/) and here is the git repository (https://github.com/myaseen208/babelquarto1)

Comment: I found that `Version in ES` directs to [http://myaseen208.com/es/index.es.html](http://myaseen208.com/es/index.es.html) rather than to [http://myaseen208.com/babelquarto1/es/index.es.html](http://myaseen208.com/babelquarto1/es/index.es.html). Same is true with `Version in FR`. Any thoughts please.

Comment: Any possible solution @shafee.

Comment: Eagerly waiting for it @shafee.

Comment: You deserve it.

Comment: Will give it a try with website too as well as try to use Urdu @shafee. Thanks